# Trouble porting movable-type's latlong-gridref javascript to java

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, eclipse

I'm having trouble porting movable-type's latlong-gridref from JavaScript to Java. I've made a little headway but stuck now.

**Issues I'm having with porting code:**

1. I'm a little lost porting the OsGridRef function ( can't really make heads or tails of it)
2. Similarly can't figure out how to  sort out LatLon from osGridToLatLong function

**Purpose of code:**

To convert Ordnance Survey grid reference easting/northing coordinates to (OSGB36) latitude/longitude

**Link to original JavaScript:**

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html

**Original JavaScript and code I've managed to port so far is below:**

## Original

```
/**
 * Creates a OsGridRef object
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {Number} easting:  Easting in metres from OS false origin
 * @param {Number} northing: Northing in metres from OS false origin
 */
function OsGridRef(easting, northing) {
  this.easting = parseInt(easting, 10);
  this.northing = parseInt(northing, 10);
}


/**
 * Convert Ordnance Survey grid reference easting/northing coordinate to (OSGB36) latitude/longitude
 *
 * @param {OsGridRef} easting/northing to be converted to latitude/longitude
 * @return {LatLon} latitude/longitude (in OSGB36) of supplied grid reference
 */
OsGridRef.osGridToLatLong = function(gridref) {
  var E = gridref.easting;
  var N = gridref.northing;

  var a = 6377563.396, b = 6356256.909;              // Airy 1830 major & minor semi-axes
  var F0 = 0.9996012717;                             // NatGrid scale factor on central meridian
  var lat0 = 49*Math.PI/180, lon0 = -2*Math.PI/180;  // NatGrid true origin
  var N0 = -100000, E0 = 400000;                     // northing & easting of true origin, metres
  var e2 = 1 - (b*b)/(a*a);                          // eccentricity squared
  var n = (a-b)/(a+b), n2 = n*n, n3 = n*n*n;

  var lat=lat0, M=0;
  do {
    lat = (N-N0-M)/(a*F0) + lat;

    var Ma = (1 + n + (5/4)*n2 + (5/4)*n3) * (lat-lat0);
    var Mb = (3*n + 3*n*n + (21/8)*n3) * Math.sin(lat-lat0) * Math.cos(lat+lat0);
    var Mc = ((15/8)*n2 + (15/8)*n3) * Math.sin(2*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(2*(lat+lat0));
    var Md = (35/24)*n3 * Math.sin(3*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(3*(lat+lat0));
    M = b * F0 * (Ma - Mb + Mc - Md);                // meridional arc

  } while (N-N0-M >= 0.00001);  // ie until < 0.01mm

  var cosLat = Math.cos(lat), sinLat = Math.sin(lat);
  var nu = a*F0/Math.sqrt(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat);              // transverse radius of curvature
  var rho = a*F0*(1-e2)/Math.pow(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat, 1.5);  // meridional radius of curvature
  var eta2 = nu/rho-1;

  var tanLat = Math.tan(lat);
  var tan2lat = tanLat*tanLat, tan4lat = tan2lat*tan2lat, tan6lat = tan4lat*tan2lat;
  var secLat = 1/cosLat;
  var nu3 = nu*nu*nu, nu5 = nu3*nu*nu, nu7 = nu5*nu*nu;
  var VII = tanLat/(2*rho*nu);
  var VIII = tanLat/(24*rho*nu3)*(5+3*tan2lat+eta2-9*tan2lat*eta2);
  var IX = tanLat/(720*rho*nu5)*(61+90*tan2lat+45*tan4lat);
  var X = secLat/nu;
  var XI = secLat/(6*nu3)*(nu/rho+2*tan2lat);
  var XII = secLat/(120*nu5)*(5+28*tan2lat+24*tan4lat);
  var XIIA = secLat/(5040*nu7)*(61+662*tan2lat+1320*tan4lat+720*tan6lat);

  var dE = (E-E0), dE2 = dE*dE, dE3 = dE2*dE, dE4 = dE2*dE2, dE5 = dE3*dE2, dE6 = dE4*dE2, dE7 = dE5*dE2;
  lat = lat - VII*dE2 + VIII*dE4 - IX*dE6;
  var lon = lon0 + X*dE - XI*dE3 + XII*dE5 - XIIA*dE7;

  return new LatLon(lat.toDeg(), lon.toDeg());
}
```

## What I've managed to port

```
LatLon osGridToLatLong(OsGridRef osGridRef) {

        int E = osGridRef.easting;
          int N = osGridRef.northing;


          double a = 6377563.396, b = 6356256.910;              // Airy 1830 major & minor semi-axes
          double F0 = 0.9996012717;                             // NatGrid scale factor on central meridian
          double lat0 = 49*Math.PI/180, lon0 = -2*Math.PI/180;  // NatGrid true origin
          double N0 = -100000, E0 = 400000;                     // northing & easting of true origin, metres
          double e2 = 1 - (b*b)/(a*a);                          // eccentricity squared
          double n = (a-b)/(a+b), n2 = n*n, n3 = n*n*n;

          double lat=lat0, M=0;


          int count = 0;
          do {
              count++;
            lat = (N-N0-M)/(a*F0) + lat;
            double Ma = (1 + n + (5.0/4)*n2 + (5.0/4)*n3) * (lat-lat0);

            double Mb = (3*n + 3*n*n + (21/8)*n3) * Math.sin(lat-lat0) * Math.cos(lat+lat0);
            double Mc = ((15/8)*n2 + (15/8)*n3) * Math.sin(2*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(2*(lat+lat0));
            double Md = (35/24)*n3 * Math.sin(3*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(3*(lat+lat0));
            M = b * F0 * (Ma - Mb + Mc - Md);                // meridional arc


          } while (N-N0-M >= 0.00001);  // ie until < 0.01mm

          double cosLat = Math.cos(lat), sinLat = Math.sin(lat);
          double nu = a*F0/Math.sqrt(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat);              // transverse radius of curvature
          double rho = a*F0*(1-e2)/Math.pow(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat, 1.5);  // meridional radius of curvature
          double eta2 = nu/rho-1;

          double tanLat = Math.tan(lat);
          double tan2lat = tanLat*tanLat, tan4lat = tan2lat*tan2lat, tan6lat = tan4lat*tan2lat;
          double secLat = 1/cosLat;
          double nu3 = nu*nu*nu, nu5 = nu3*nu*nu, nu7 = nu5*nu*nu;
          double VII = tanLat/(2*rho*nu);
          double VIII = tanLat/(24*rho*nu3)*(5+3*tan2lat+eta2-9*tan2lat*eta2);
          double IX = tanLat/(720*rho*nu5)*(61+90*tan2lat+45*tan4lat);
          double X = secLat/nu;
          double XI = secLat/(6*nu3)*(nu/rho+2*tan2lat);
          double XII = secLat/(120*nu5)*(5+28*tan2lat+24*tan4lat);
          double XIIA = secLat/(5040*nu7)*(61+662*tan2lat+1320*tan4lat+720*tan6lat);

          double dE = (E-E0), dE2 = dE*dE, dE3 = dE2*dE, dE4 = dE2*dE2, dE5 = dE3*dE2, dE6 = dE4*dE2, dE7 = dE5*dE2;
          lat = lat - VII*dE2 + VIII*dE4 - IX*dE6;
          double lon = lon0 + X*dE - XI*dE3 + XII*dE5 - XIIA*dE7;

          return new LatLon(lat.toDeg(), lon.toDeg());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience with Javascript?  Just looking at what you have posted, I can tell you that OsGridRef is a class.  To make that is Java:

```
class OsGridRef {
  public int easting;
  public int northing;

  public OsGridRef (String easting, String northing) {
    this.easting = Interger.parseInt(easting);
    this.northing = Integer.parseInt(northing);
  }
}
```

That would work with the code you have, even if it's not best practice, but I'm not sure what to tell you about the rest.  toDeg() probably comes from some library that's being used, so you'll have to figure out where that came from in order to port that.  If I knew what it was before converting it to degrees I could offer some guidance, but just looking at it I have no idea.